# Parse date time format "2013-12-09 12:14:09.994844+10" in Android

Tags: java, android, datetime

I need to parse string value of `data = "2013-12-09 12:14:09.994844+10"` with `SimpleDateFormat`.

I'm using `format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"`, but it's not working.

How can I solve this problem?

```
public class Test {

    public static final String FORMAT1 = "hh:mm aa dd.MM.yyyy";
    public static final String FORMAT2 = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Time = "
                + getDate("2013-12-09 12:14:09.994844+10",
                DateTimeUtils.FORMAT2, DateTimeUtils.FORMAT1));
    }

    public static String getDate(String inputDate, String inputFormat,
                                 String outputFormat) {

        String strDate = "";
        SimpleDateFormat sdfInput = new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat,
                Locale.getDefault());
        SimpleDateFormat sdfOutput = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat,
                Locale.getDefault());

        if (inputDate != null) {
            Date date;
            try {
                date = sdfInput.parse(inputDate);
                strDate = sdfOutput.format(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                strDate = "";
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return strDate.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean?

Comment: What you have try? Post you code here...

Comment: FORMAT2 = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"; is not working

Answer (score 0):

In Java SE 7 to format a timezone with one sign and two digits use the letter `'X'`. For example: `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX"`. The javadoc can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone).

In Android however the letter `'X'` is not supported but you may add two extra zeros to the date string in order to use `'Z'`. For example: `"2013-12-09 12:14:09.994844+1000"` will be correctly parsed. The javadoc for Android can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score -1):

SimpleDateFormat can't deal with microseconds.
You need to strip out the extra 3 digits.
like this:

```
data = data.substring(0, data.length()-4)+"Z";
```

Comment: the documentation states differently

Comment: @blackbelt what does it says? can you add a reference?